# Displaying results from Mysql in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am building a PDF document using FPDF, the problem i am having is that when i take data out for the database and try to show it through a loop the results write on top of one another and not below each other.

I understand why this is happening, because the cells have the same settings, but not sure how to adjust the cells to align one below the other.

Here is my code

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employment_history WHERE username ='$usernam' ORDER BY    employment_history_id ASC"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$job_title =$row['job_title'];
$company_name =$row['company_name'];
$job_description =$row['job_description'];
$from =$row['from'];
$to =$row['to'];

    $pdf->Cell(10,10, $job_title,0, 0, 'L', FALSE);                         
    $pdf->Cell(10,10, $company_name,0, 0, 'L', FALSE);

    }
```

Comment: Use a aux var and one increment of 10 in $pdf->Cell($aux...

Comment: Thanks i have tried to google your recommendation, but i can't seem to find anything and not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$pdf->Cell(10,10, $job_title,1,1,'C');                         
$pdf->Cell(10,10, $company_name,1,1,'C');
```

FPDF Cell doc: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm